# django not raising IntegrityError for duplicate primary key

Tags: python, django, django-testing

Does django enforce uniqueness for a primary key?

The documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key) seems to suggest so, but when I define a class as:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

and test this constraint in a test case:

```
class SiteTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.site = Site(id=0, name='Site')
        self.site.save()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.site.delete()

    def test_unique_id(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            badSite = Site(id=0, name='Bad Site')
            badSite.save()
            badSite.delete()
```

the test fails.

If I test on a normal field (primary_key=False, unique=True) then the exception is raised correctly.  Setting unique=True on the id field does not change the result.

Is there something about primary_key fields that I'm missing here?

My database backend is MySQL, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test method is wrong. What you're doing here is updating the existing instance since you're supplying an already used primary key. Change the `save` to a `force_insert` like so.

```
def test_unique_id(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            badSite = Site(id=0, name='Bad Site')
            badSite.save(force_insert=True)
            badSite.delete()
```

The django docs explain how [django knows whether to UPDATE or INSERT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert). You should read that section.

Are you aware that django already supports automatic primary keys? See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for more of an explanation.

Comment: I'm aware that the auto primary key field is called id, but as id has actual meaning in this context I want to set it manually.  Adding unique=True to the definition does not enforce uniqueness (I had tried that already).  I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @sapi, I realised my first answer was wrong. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it.  Personally, I find this behaviour quite odd (I would expect each call to a model constructor to create a new instance/row, and only to update if I've accessed an existing model from the database), but it's clearly defined, so my mistake.

Comment: @sapi, that would mean you'd need to do a select even if you already had the details from elsewhere (which is pretty common most of the time). However I've answered two questions here in the last month that had the same assumption as you. I find the behaviour nice for the vast majority of cases.